# Redirect from system.out.println to a memo

Tags: java, redirect, zk

I have a internal logic in my application that displays results and time processing of certain tasks, but now I started to develop my user interface and I need to show these results in the memo (I'm using ZK framework). But the logic is located in a internal class...so how I can change this class to redirect the output information in the memo instead of console ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been better to use a logging framework or an own report writer interface wich first have implemented by `System.out.println()` and now could have been replaced by an other implementation.

But now the most simple way would be to set `System.out` by `System.setOut()`. The needed `PrintStream` can be created on any `File` or better `OutputStream`.

But to fill a chart model of ZK you need to parse the data printed to `System.out`. That sounds like a bad idea. Try to refactor the (console) app first.

Answer (score 1):

use `System.setOut()` and `system.setErr()`. Pass there ByteArrayOutpuStream wrapped with PrintStream. Then extract bytes.